# Indenting code by bracket column index in Vim?

Tags: vim, erlang, indentation

I'm using Vim to edit Erlang code. I'm used to (most Erlang programmers do this) to indent Erlang code by the bracket scope they're in. For example, C is often indented one tab width inside curly brackets:

```
int main(void) {
    printf("hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

In Erlang, it's common to indent based on the column where the bracket started:

```
?assertError({bad_options, [{foo, bar},
                            bad_option]},
             lhttpc:request("http://localhost/", get, [], <<>>, 1000,
                            [bad_option, {foo, bar}])).
```

(Example above is indented to get the point across, not according to subjective beauty).

Tab width would be used if the block is started on a new line:

```
?assertError(
    {bad_options, [{foo, bar}, bad_option]},
    lhttpc:request(
         "http://localhost/", get, [], <<>>, 1000,
         [bad_option, {foo, bar}]
    )
).
```

Relevant parts of my .vimrc:

```csh
set expandtab " Spaces for tabs "
set tabstop=4 " Tab width 4 "
set shiftwidth=4
set smarttab
set autoindent

" Enable filetype plugin "
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
```

Is there a  way to perform this indentation in Vim, and if so, how?

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/jimenezrick/vimerl?

Comment: I realized that I'm actually using `vimerl` and updated to the latest version. But no, it still indents to 1 (or 2 sometimes, strangely enough) tab widths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a fork of vimerl which implements "context aware indentation" instead of "static indentation": https://github.com/aszlig/vimerl.git

Seems to work, so I'll roll with that for a while.

Comment: Hi, @Adam Lindberg. It's been a week. How do you feel about vimerl? I have exactly the same requirements as you. Thanks!

Comment: That fork seem to indent according to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

This looks you need delve into the murky world of `cindent` and `cinoptions`. I believe that putting the following in your vimrc will partially meet your needs:

```
set cindent
set cinoptions+=(0
```

But the question is how this will affect other behaviour. See `help cinoptions-values` for much more information. It should possible to achieve precisely what you want, but it might take some experimenting.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks somewhat promising, but I can't figure out what options to use. Tried a lot of things but didn't get anything remotely usable. Suspect that maybe the Erlang plugin messes things up as well since it has it's own indentation.

Comment: Have you tried using `set cinoptions?` to find the value set by the Erlang changes (without any of your changes)? Does the plugin claim to improve the indenting? If so, it might be difficult to adjust it from outside the plugin.

Comment: Default `cinoptions` seems empty. The plugin seem to do some [manual indenting](https://github.com/jimenezrick/vimerl/blob/master/indent/erlang.vim) work, which might make it hard to fix.